# Error in check_input(x) In R Sentiment Analysis

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

This keeps appearing in my code after writing unnest_tokens:

> Error in check_input(x) : 
>     Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
>     vectors, each of which has a length of 1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(tibble)

amazon_reviews <- read.csv(file="c:\\Datafiniti_Amazon_Consumer_Reviews_of_Amazon_Products.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
amazon_reviews <- data.frame(amazon_reviews, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
tidy_amazon_reviews <- amazon_reviews %>%
  unnest_tokens(words,reviews) %>%
  select(-dateAdded,-dataUpdated,-asins,-brand,-categories,-primaryCategories,-imageURLs,-keys,-manufacturer,-manufacturerNumber,-reviews.date,-reviews.dateAdded,-reviews.dateSeen,reviews.doRecommend,-reviews.id,-reviews.numHelpful,reviews.rating,-reviews.sourceURLs,reviews.text,-reviews.title,-reviews.username,-sourceURLs,-ï..id) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)
```